# SOAPUI call an update method then call a get to check the update worked

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAP UI to test some Java SAOP webservices that I wrote.  I am trying to call an update method and then call a get method to verify the results in an assertion.  Now, the Update method doesn't return any results (the reason why I have to call a get method to verify the results) so am I forced to always have two steps to do this?  Or can mold this whole thing into one step to kind of streamline my unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there anyway you can rewrite your webservice to return more information when an update call is successful? SoapUI is only going to show whatever is exposed by the service you wrote.

But to try and actually answer your question, supposing nothing is returned except a status code of some kind when you do your update, yes you will always need to have two steps for this. You can set up Properties to store the criteria you need and use these properties by scoping them in the actual tests.

Comment: While not the answer I was hoping for, it indeed is the answer.  Unfortunately, the design does not call for returning anything other than a status code.